# Extracting strings between specific characters in excel and separating them with a comma

Tags: excel

Is there a way to extract multiple strings between specific characters in excel and separating them with a comma.

For example:

[image]

I am thankful for every help!

Comment: just find and replace the [ and the ] to nothing

Comment: But it is only extracting the first string, not all of them :(

Comment: Which version of excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2007

Comment: @Basch, see my edited answer, which should probably work on Excel-2007 for a maximum four sets of parenthesis.  For more you have to modify the formula by adding similar syntax at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you are using too old version of excel which lacks dynamic array functions and besides too many other useful functions, You may probably have to do a long workaround here.

**First** using `substitute` and `len` You have to find out number of such square parenthesis in each of the row.  Thereafter you have to work out the formula of `max` of such numbers.

**Do it like this**

Assuming your text-values in `A2` for a max of 4 occurrences enter the following formula in `B2`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(A2,FIND("]",A2&"]")-1),1,FIND("[",A2&"["),"")&" "&REPLACE(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("]",2),"]","#",2))-1),1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("[",2),"[","#",2)),"")&" "&REPLACE(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("]",3),"]","#",3))-1),1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("[",3),"[","#",3)),"")&" "&REPLACE(LEFT(A2,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("]",4),"]","#",4))-1),1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A2&REPT("[",4),"[","#",4)),"")), " ", ", ")
```

Let's say this is the text in A2

```
I have a text [123] and some more [4523] and also [552222] how to extract [22]?
```

This will create a output of `123,4523,552222,22` in `B2`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*The following requires a version of Excel O365 that supports dynamic arrays and the `LET` function.*

If I understand correctly you are looking for something like this.

[image: target output]

This formula will list all the positions of all `[` in the string using dynamic array functions.

```
=LET(x,$B$2,
    y, SEQUENCE(LEN(x)),
    raw, IF(MID(x,y,1)="[",y,""),
    filtered, FILTER(raw,raw<>"",""),
    filtered)
```

`LET` allows you to set names within a formula using parameter pairs. The first is the name; the second is the value of the name.  The last parameter is the value returned. In this case, `x` is set to cell `B2`. `y` is set to the array listing the numbers from 1 to the length of `x` using the dynamic array function `SEQUENCE`. `raw` is a list that shows the value of `y` if that position is `[`, otherwise it is blank.  `filtered` uses the `FILTER` function to remove all of the blank rows. `filtered` is the last argument of the `LET` function so that is what is returned. If this formula is entered into cell `A4` then `A4` will show `1`, `A5` will show `14` and `A6` will show `28`.

If you then enter a similar formula in `B4` replacing `[` with `]` then the result is `{7,21,35}` in cells `B4`, `B5` and `B6`.

Finally, in cell `B2` you can enter `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,MID(A2,A4#+1,B4#-A4#-1))`.  This will return the result you are looking for.

[image]

If you are unfamiliar with dynamic arrays, `A4#` indicates an entire dynamic array starting in cell `A4`. In this case, it is the same as `A4:A6`.

- [More information on Dynamic Arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)
- [More information on LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999)

Comment: Because I am using excel 2007 this did not work, but a great solution Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by “`raw` is a list the show the value of `y`”? Also, please do _enter image description here_.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with only formulas in Excel 2007. You need VBA UDF then. With Excel O365 having dynamic formula access, this can be done like:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,TRIM(LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",REPT(" ",100)),"[","</s><s> ")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., ' ')]"),100)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no "extraction" in your question, just removal. The formula below replaces the unwanted characters with "", thereby removing them. Please try it.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"[",""),"]","")
```

Comment: And if there are random texts between them like:
[Apple] some text [Orange] some text2

Comment: Then we have a different problem, meaning a different question. Amend your question and try to think of all eventualities before you ask.